# Can we modify AbpUserConfiguration/GetAll or reduce the response time by any means

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, abp, aspnetzero

In my application, the response time for the API call - AbpUserConfiguration/GetAll is around 3-7 seconds, not just the first time. This API is called when the user logs in. Is there any way that I can optimize this to make the UI load faster?

[NetworkTab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P2Up.png)

This API call refers AbpUserConfiguration/GetAll.
I believe its an internal part of ABP framework that cant be edited.
Is there any way around to find out why its taking this long and then try to optimize it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you are tiered/seperate AuthServer solution, it might be related to the `redis`. Otherwise it is hard to diagnose with so limited information.

If this problem occurs on the commercial template, you can raise a new question at https://support.abp.io/QA/Questions

If it is the community edition, you can create a new issue with reproduction steps at https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues